# Ruby on Rails template "extend" as in Django

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I came from Django and Python background to RoR. My question in simple. Let's say, I have one `application.html.erb` layout.

I want to make another layout called `management.html.erg` which will inherit `application.html.erb` and be able to use its yields and so on.

Something like `{% extends "template.html" %}` in django.

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example of what you want to achieve. I do not know the django syntax, I am curious what the concept of "extending" a template would mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for ActionView helper `content_for` and `yield`.
See guide about [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for a brief overview and apidock for detailed documentation.

`yield` is an analogue of Django's `block` tag

[content_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for) is an analogue of `extends` tag.

Layout for which the content is selected is driven from a controller so there is no point to manually specify its name like in Django.